# Select all column data but distinct on column

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * DISTINCT `contact_id`  
 FROM `survey_response_single`  
  WHERE text_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 15
```

i will want to fetch all columns data using distinct query

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like he wants to access all the columns. So while using DISTINCT, one has to specify all the columns but as you can't use *

But if we use GROUP BY, this problem could be solved. As in GROUP BY you will get only distinct values of `contact_id` as similar values would be grouped. Moreover now we can access all columns using *

```
SELECT * FROM `survey_response_single`  
WHERE text_id = '1' 
GROUP BY `contact_id`
```

Comment: Well how are columns even dependent on group by.

Comment: First of all, it looks like he wants to access all the columns. So while using DISTINCT, one has to specify all the columns but as you can't use *

Comment: SO if we use GROUP BY, this problem is solved as in GROUP BY you will get only distinct values of `contact_id` as similar values would be grouped. Moreover now we can access all columns using *.

Comment: So if you group by contact_id you can only have that and aggregate functions in your select columns list. You can't have *. Have a try mate :)

Comment: Dude we can also use aggregate functions but it is not required to do so. Moreover at the same time we are getting distinct values and can use * simultaneously.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I answered in terms of SQL Server. My bad ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try below of any depends on which output you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id, text_id, details  -- take your column names
FROM survey_response_single  
WHERE text_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 15
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d502/4

or this(if you want only single column's distinct values):

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id
FROM survey_response_single  
WHERE text_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 15
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d502/6

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `survey_response_single` WHERE `text_id` = '1' LIMIT 0, 15' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Easy going:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `contact_id`, *
FROM `survey_response_single`
WHERE `text_id` = '1' LIMIT 0, 15
```

What many doesnt know: '*' doesnt have to be the only statement within a SELECT. You can easily seperate it by comma and fetch more columns.

You call DISTINCT on the target column and also fetch all other columns with star.

The only side-effect is that your result table will contain two "contact_id" columns with identical content. But you dont need to worry about an alias when fetching the array with PHP this will work either way.

If you want a query without duplicate data you have no choice but to list all columns of the table by yourself instead of using *

Comment: please add some explanation to your code which will help others to understand it quickly.

Comment: I thought it was pretty much self explaining but fine I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `contact_id`,column1,
column2 FROM `survey_response_single`
WHERE text_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 15  "); //You select here the required data 
//of column1,2... and having distinct contact_id values
$execute_query=mysql_query($query,$db_conn);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($execute_query){
  //use you data
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `contact_id`  
 FROM `survey_response_single`  
  WHERE text_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 15
```

Answer (score -1):

star (*) is not require

```
SELECT  DISTINCT `contact_id`  
 FROM `survey_response_single`  
  WHERE text_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 15
```

remove * sign

Comment: He said he want to fetch all columns, then he needs the * or needs to list all columns of the table manually. The star is easier in this case...